# Pythonic way to make datetime object

Tags: python, date, datetime

Curently I am using this:

```
from datetime import datetime
startDate = datetime.strptime('03.12.2004', '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Is there some simpler/Pythonic way ?

Comment: I'd say it's already pretty Pythonic and simple

Comment: how could it be simpler?

Comment: look here for a list of available methods: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Are you manually entering the date as a string in order to get the `datetime` object you want? If so, you can use `datetime.datetime(2004, 3, 12)` instead.

Comment: I might even go as far as to say that it is perfect.

Comment: @Nicholas Please put it as answer, so that I can except it. But shouldn't it be (2004, 12 ,3) ? Thanks

Comment: @WebOrCode you're right. I misread your format originally and thought I was looking at a m/d/y format. Official answer added below. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to initialize a `datetime` object instead of using the string above:

```
datetime.datetime(2004, 12, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that shorter is better, but I find it easier to read if you're going to have a lot of lines creating datetimes, of course assuming 'dt' doesn't clash with anything else in your code.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

start = dt(2004, 12, 3)
```